# how to use preg_match find string pattern for two or three specific word

Tags: php

```
$lines ="do you want to cut paper here?";
$pattern = "do you '/(.*) to (.*)/' paper here?";

$matches = array();
preg_match($pattern, $lines, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

I got an error , I think the syntax i use was incorrect, I tried many similar code but it's not meet my requirement. Can anyone please suggest how to get the word that matches ?

in this example `$matches[1]` should be want and `$matches[2]` should be cut

thank you in advance

Comment: try `$pattern = "/do you (.*) to (.*) paper here?/";`?

Comment: [`sscanf`](http://php.net/sscanf) might be more in line with your placeholder-style approach. (Not really better than a regex, it's just a more basic option.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, this is working regex:

```
<?php
$lines ="do you want to cut paper here?"; 
$pattern = "/do you ([^\s]+) to ([^\s]+) paper here\?/";

preg_match($pattern, $lines, $matches);
var_dump($matches);

?>
```

**it prints this result:**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(30) "do you want to cut paper here?"
  [1]=> string(4) "want"
  [2]=> string(3) "cut"
}
```

Comment: Just `\S+` would be simpler than the charclass, or `\w+` more specific for extracting words.

Comment: @mario, thank you for your comment. I agree with what you've suggested, I've used a char class so that it's easier for him to add other separators if needed (like commas, dot etc.). Anyway for the string he gave us, your suggestion is better than a char class as you said

Answer (score 0):

I agree with mario, `sscanf()` is a better choice.  `sscanf()` doesn't create a "fullstring match" like `preg_match()` does, in other words it doesn't make more data than is required.

Also, you don't need to match the entire string, just the string up to the final word to be extracted.

`%s` in the format string means one or more continuous non-whitespace characters.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YptpC))

```
$string = "do you want to cut paper here?";
$format = "do you %s to %s";
var_export(sscanf($string, $format));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'want',
  1 => 'cut',
)
```